# powershell how to use ".clock" function of "media player"

Tags: 64-bit, windows-8.1, powershell-4.0

I have built a form using PowerShell to help my kids learn French numbers. The form plays the French pronunciation of a random number from a section of an MP3 audio file that contains all French pronunciations of 0 to 100. This all works fine using:

```
$zMediaPlayer = New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer;
$zMediaPlayer.Open($zMediaFile);
. . . . 
$zMediaPlayer.Position = New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, $zStartAt);
$zMediaPlayer.Play();
Sleep -Milliseconds $zDuration;
$zMediaPlayer.Pause();
$zMediaPlayer.Stop();
. . . . .
$zMediaPlayer.Close();
```

I have seen mention of a "clock" property of System Media Player that allows both 'StartAt' and 'Duration' to be used in a 'TimeLine' to play a section of a media file:

```
Public property Clock Gets or sets the MediaClock associated with the MediaTimeline to be played.
```

But I cannot find how to use this type of functionality in a PowerShell script as I have another idea for a script where such functionality would be very useful. Can someone describe how to use this functionality, thanks.